# htaccess - redirect multiples files into subfolders to parent folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am looking to rewrite the url, like this: 
From:

```
http://localhost/system/view/mod001/m1_file_01.php (or any file inside mod001)
or 
http://localhost/system/view/mod002/m2_file_01.php (or any file inside mod002)
```

To

```
http://localhost/system/m?_file_01.php
```

I mean, hide/remove the **view** folder and the **(mod001|mod002|mod003|etc)** folder, and I have not gotten.

This is my folders structure:

```
-system/
    .htaccess
    index.php
    view/
        mod001/
            m1_file_01.php | m1_file_02.php | ...
        mod002/
            m2_file_01.php | m2_file_02.php | ...
        media/
            css/ | js/ | ...
```

And this is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase / #Yeah is commented
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /system/ [L,R=301]
```

How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would likely need a different rule for each of the 3 possible digits in `modXXX` because you can't really string pad with regular expressions. Something like this might work, but I haven't tested it:

```
#match 1 digit
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (m([0-9])_.*\.php) view/mod00$2/$1 [QSA,L]

#match 2 digits
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (m([0-9][0-9])_.*\.php) view/mod0$2/$1 [QSA,L]

#match 3 digits
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (m([0-9][0-9][0-9])_.*\.php) view/mod$2/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This is useful, but I'm afraid I did not explain well in my example.

The files within folders mod001| mod002 can have any name (not begin precisely with 'm1_') and no two files with the same name within those folders (ie, if a file called hola.php exists in the 'mod001' folder; in the folders mod002 or  mod003, there will be no file hola.php) and the idea is you can not see the extension .php

Comment: @ManuelFernándezLévano Then it can't be done with .htaccess and would likely suck pretty bad in any other method. The only way to do it would be to route all requests to a single php script and have that check every folder until it finds the requested file which would be horrible for performance because as you add more folders, the more places it needs to search.

Comment: That's what I feared. After much thought and not knowing much about .htaccess, I decided to do it with PHP. Thank you very much anyway for the help.

Comment: That isn't a horrible way. Many/most frameworks do exactly that (route all requests through a single file that routes the request to other files via include or by calling a class method).

Comment: That's right. Not what I had in mind originally, but now that I have, works great!
Thanks for your help, I have learned a little more about .htaccess ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's imagine that you want to get `m1_file_02.php` and then you want to get `m2_file_02.php`
How the server can guess forwhich exact file/folder you want to send request to?
You have to specify **an unique** identificator for each folder. 
Anyway, `http://localhost/system/m?_file_01.php` it can't be using that structure you've given.

Comment: From what I can see, the file starts with `m1` which corresponds to `mod001` where `m2` corresponds to `mod002`. It appears to be left padding to 3 digits with zeroes.